# How to set items to a specific Todolist in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Im building a TODO app using django rest framework. I have to two models namely todolist and todoitem.How can I set a new todoitem to a specific todolist? I tried using foreign key but it didn't worked out,Sorry for my bad english,Can anyone please help me

My `models.py`:

```
class todolist(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class todoitem(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    due_by = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(todolist,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def _unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

My `classviews.py`:

```
class Todolist(LoginRequiredMixin,ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = listserializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = todolist.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(Todolist, self).get_queryset()

class Todolistdetail(LoginRequiredMixin,RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = todolist.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(Todolistdetail, self).get_queryset()
    serializer_class = listserializer

class Todoitem(LoginRequiredMixin,ListCreateAPIView):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        temp = self.queryset(todolist.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']))
        serializer.save(parent=temp)

    def get_queryset(self):
        temp = todolist.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.queryset = todoitem.objects.filter(parent=temp)
        return super(Todoitem, self).get_queryset()
    serializer_class = itemserializer

class Todoitemdetail(LoginRequiredMixin,RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        temp = todolist.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['list_id'])
        self.queryset = todoitem.objects.filter(parent=temp)
        return super(Todoitemdetail, self).get_queryset()
    serializer_class = itemserializer
```

My `serializers.py`:

```
class listserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = todolist
        fields = '__all__'

class itemserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='todolist.id')
    class Meta:
        model = todoitem
        fields = '__all__'
```

My `urls.py`:

```
from todoapp import classviews
app_name = "todoapp"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$',classviews.Todolist.as_view(),name="list_lists"),
    url(r'^list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',classviews.Todolistdetail.as_view(),name="each_list"),
    url(r'^list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/item/$',classviews.Todoitem.as_view(),name="list_items"),
    url(r'^list/(?P<list_id>[0-9]+)/item/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',classviews.Todoitemdetail.as_view(),name="each_item")

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
class TodoitemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Todoitem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = itemserializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated)
```

serializer.py

```
class itemserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=todoitem
        fields='__all__'
```

url:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todo_item', TodoitemViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

jsut post data `{'parent':1 'description':'example',....}` to `www.example.com/todo_item/`, parent is your todolist'id.